# Python3 Asyncio shared resources between concurrent tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, python-asyncio, shared-resource

I've got a network application written in Python3.5 which takes advantage of pythons Asyncio which concurrently handles each incoming connection.

On every concurrent connection, I want to store the connected clients data in a list. I'm worried that if two clients connect at the same time (which is a possibility) then both tasks will attempt to write to the list at the same time, which will surely raise an issue. How would I solve this?

Comment: if you're doing HTTP you should use `aiohttp`, which (AFAIK) takes care of all of that for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

asyncio does context switching only on *yield points* (`await` expressions), thus two parallel tasks are not executed at **the same** time.

But if race conditions are still possible (it depends on concrete code structure) you may use [asyncio synchronization primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html) and [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html).

Comment: Each client connection is handled by an individual task. Within each task, when the client is being handled, data is appended to a global list. `task = asyncio.Task(self._handle_client(client_reader, client_writer))
        self.clients[task] = (client_reader, client_writer)` and within `_handle_client` the list is being appended to. Will this cause an issue if two clients connect at the exact same time?

Comment: No, it's pretty safe.

Answer (score 4):

There is lots of info that is missing in your question.

- Is your app threaded? If yes, then you have to wrap your list in a `threading.Lock`.
- Do you switch context (e.g. use `await`) between writes (to the list) in the request handler? If yes, then you have to wrap your list in a `asyncio.Lock`.
- Do you do multiprocessing? If yes then you have to use `multiprocessing.Lock`
- Is your app divided onto multiple machines? Then you have to use some external shared database (e.g. Redis).

If answers to all of those questions is *no* then you don't have to do anything since single-threaded async app cannot update shared resource parallely.